# SSE cumulative summing

Tags: c++, performance, sse

I have a simple problem. Having a starting uint_32 value (say 125) and a __m128i of operands to add, for example (+5,+10,-1,-5). What I would like to get as fast as possible is a vector (125 + 5, 125 + 5 + 10, 125 + 5 + 10 - 1, 125 + 5 + 10 - 1 - 5), i.e. cumulatively add values from the operands to the starting value. So far the only solution I can think of is doing an addition of 4 __m128i variables. For the example, they would be

```
/* pseudoSSE code... */
__m128i src =     (125,125,125,125)
__m128i operands =(5,10,-1,-5)

/*  Here I omit the partitioning of operands into add1,..add4 for brevity  */

__m128i add1 =    (+05,+05,+05,+05)
__m128i add2 =    (+00,+10,+10,+10)
__m128i add3 =    (+00,+00,-01,-01)
__m128i add4 =    (+00,+00,+00,-05)
__m128i res1 = _mm_add_epu32( add1, add2 )
__m128i res2 = _mm_add_epu32( add3, add4 )
__m128i res3 = _mm_add_epu32( res1, add2 )
__m128i res  = _mm_add_epu32( res3, src  )
```

Like this, I get what I wanted. For this solution I am going to need to set all add_ variables and then perform 4 additions. What Im really asking is whether this can be done faster. Either via some different algo or maybe using some specialized SSE functions that I do not know yet (something like _mm_cumulative_sum()). Many thanks.

Comment: How can you possibly come to the conclusion that using SSE will be slow doing that??? Have you tested it?

Comment: I don't understand. You say you have a 32bit value, and yet you show having four 8-bit values? What are those 5 lines of "code" supposed to *mean*? And why would you have to load values 4 times?

Comment: @Tony The Lion: That's not my point! Ofc SSE will be the fastest solution. What I mean is - isnt there a better algorithm (in the SSE framework) than doing these 4 additions?

Comment: @jalf: Those 5 lines were just an example, I wanted it to be as instrcutive as possible, hence I wrote it with small numbers. In general, there will be really 32b u_integers.

Comment: But what those lines an example **of**? What are they supposed to do? No matter how I look at it, I can't see how it relates to your question

Comment: @jalf: Those are an example of how I want to do it..how to get the vector of (125+5, 125+5+10, 125+5+10-1, 125+5+10-1-5).

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't make much sense of your question. What you're asking here in my mind is "How can I speed up the addition of four numbers with something other than SSE?"

Comment: There isn't really a faster way to do it than what you're outlining then.

Comment: You have given an example with 10 additions. Do you want to know if there is a way to do it in less than 4 packed SSE additions?

Comment: I cannot really see what's so hard to understand about this question, even before the edit.

Comment: My hint: check the Intel C++ Intrinsic Reference for an instruction that fits your needs: http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/9/4/c/8/e/18072-347603.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all guys for your help. Determined to figure out which version is the fastest, I wrote a test app.

1/ nonSSE version does all the stuff just as you would expect.

```
int iRep;
int iCycle;
int iVal = 25;
int a1, a2, a3, a4;
int dst1 [4];
for ( iCycle = 0; iCycle < CYCLE_COUNT; iCycle++ )
    for ( iRep = 0; iRep < REP_COUNT; iRep++ )
        {   
          a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = iRep;
          dst1[0] = iVal + a1;
          dst1[1] = dst1[0] + a2;
          dst1[2] = dst1[1] + a3;
          dst1[3] = dst1[2] + a4;
        }
```

2/ SSE-4 additions does what I proposed, i.e.

```
__m128i _a1, _a2, _a3, _a4;
__m128i _res1, _res2, _res3;
__m128i _val;
__m128i _res;

for ( iCycle = 0; iCycle < CYCLE_COUNT; iCycle++ )
    for ( iRep = 0; iRep < REP_COUNT; iRep++ ){ 
        a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = iRep;

        _val = _mm_set1_epi32( iVal );
        _a1  = _mm_set_epi32 (a1, a1, a1, a1 );
        _a2  = _mm_set_epi32 (a2, a2, a2, 0  );
        _a3  = _mm_set_epi32 (a3, a3, 0 , 0  );
        _a4  = _mm_set_epi32 (a4, 0 , 0 , 0  );

        _res1 = _mm_add_epi32( _a1, _a2     );
        _res2 = _mm_add_epi32( _a3, _a4     );
        _res3 = _mm_add_epi32( _val, _res1  );
        _res  = _mm_add_epi32( _res3, _res2 );
    }
```

3/ SSE-3 additions does what Evgeny proposed, i.e.

```
__m128i shift1, shift2, operands ;
for ( iCycle = 0; iCycle < CYCLE_COUNT; iCycle++ )
    for ( iRep = 0; iRep < REP_COUNT; iRep++ ){ 
        a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = iRep;

        _val = _mm_set1_epi32( iVal );
        operands = _mm_set_epi32(a1,a2,a3,a4);

        shift1 = _mm_add_epi32( operands,               
                 _mm_and_si128(_mm_shuffle_epi32(operands, 0xF9),   _mm_set_epi32(0,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF)   ));
        shift2 = _mm_add_epi32( shift1, 
                 _mm_and_si128(_mm_shuffle_epi32(shift1, 0xFE),     _mm_set_epi32(0,0,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF)            ));
        _res = _mm_add_epi32(_val, shift2); 
        }
```

The results for

```
 #define REP_COUNT    100000
 #define CYCLE_COUNT  100000
```

are

```
  non-SSE        -> 6.118s
  SSE-4additions -> 20.775s
  SSE-3additions -> 14.873s
```

Rather surprising...

Answer (score 5):

You can add some more parallelism and use 3 additions instead of 4:

```
const __m128i src = _mm_set1_epi32(125);
const __m128i operands = _mm_set_epi32(5,10,-1,-5);

const __m128i shift1 =
  _mm_add_epi32(operands,
    _mm_and_si128(_mm_shuffle_epi32(operands, 0xF9),
                  _mm_set_epi32(0,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF)));

const __m128i shift2 =
  _mm_add_epi32(shift1,
    _mm_and_si128(_mm_shuffle_epi32(shift1, 0xFE),
                  _mm_set_epi32(0,0,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF)));

const __m128i res = _mm_add_epi32(src, shift2);
```

Here SSE2 instruction set is used. With newer instruction sets you can substitute _mm_and_si128/_mm_shuffle_epi32 with a single instruction like _mm_shuffle_epi8.

Cumulative sum is calculated with 2 additions as shown below:

```
   a    b    c    d
 +      a    b    c
  ------------------
   a   a+b  b+c  c+d
 +           a   a+b
  ------------------
   a   a+b a+b+c a+b+c+d
```

SSE does not fit well for tasks like this. Its performance  is good only for "vertical" operations, but it requires a lot of additional work for "horizontal" operations, needed here.

Comment: Evgeny, thank you! I wrote an app trying to analyze which version runs the fastest, however MSVC 2010 seems to cut out all the code for me ("optimization"). I would like to post the results, but for that I need to first ask: when I turn optimizations off, does the resulting runtime of each version tell me about efficiency? I mean, when I turn optim off, doesnt it somehow harm the efficiency of SSE functions? Because with optim off, nonSSE runs 4x faster than SSE. However, I dont know how else to tell compiler not to cut out my "improductive" code (repeating something 1M times). Many thanks.

Comment: @DanBencik: if you turn optimizations off, it should harm the efficiency of both SSE and non-SSE functions. So it's not a good idea to test performance without optimizations. To tell compiler not to cut out "unproductive" code, you can accumulate some piece of the computations' results in a variable, then either print it to console, or send it to some other external function, or write to volatile variable.